# Identify logged users in cloud based web app

Tags: java, spring, oracle

Is there a way to identify who are logged users in particular moment on cloud based web application. My application is implemented using java spring. Database is Oracle.

Comment: If someone simply closes a browser window, are they logged in or logged out

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are using to do authentication. 
For example if you are using org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2

You can use the following associated tables to determine who is actually logged in:
users;
oauth_access_token;
oauth_client_token;
oauth_refresh_token;
oauth_code;
audit_event_data;

Or alternatively hook into the authentication lifecycle and manually persist the authenticated users.

Your question is too broad but yes it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 0):

Do you manage users' sessions at your server. If so, you could determine who and how many users are logged-in at a particular moment.

Answer (score 0):

If stateful (server stores the client sessions), try following:

```
@Autowired
SessionRegistry sessionRegistry;
...
sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals();
```

If stateless:

There is no such case as "logged in users". Anyway you may able to track them if you can log user's "last access time" through an interceptor as for example.